# "Daily vote limit reached; come back in 8 hours." makes no sense when reporting offensive messages

Tags: feature-request, flags

Simple problem. With one Q, a few members think it's fun to make a few annoying posts, or generate noise or just be obnoxious. Of course, there's a nice little flag that can flag them as offensive...

But why can't I flag more than 8 comments while the ones making offensive remarks and noise can still just continue to be obnoxious???

So, a feature request: Can this limit be higher or even remove it altogether? It just makes no sense

Comment: Nearly a dupe: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15487/should-flagging-limits-be-raised

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The moderator / offensive / spam flags are indeed currently capped, and I have openly supported raising this limit for trusted users (like [this near-dup](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8935/increase-the-number-of-daily-spam-flags-with-reputation)); but we don't want a rogue low-level account spamming the system with flags etc (grudge settling, or just to be obnoxious for the sake of being obnoxious).

Comment: Couldn't the cap be tied to the rep?

Comment: That is pretty much in line with my view; I'd be happy if (for example) 3k users had twice as many flags. Not up to me, though.

Answer (score 3):

The problem with removing the flag limit on comments in particular is that comments are removed on an automated basis, permanently and silently.  They aren't even seen in the 10k user tools.

If everyone had an unlimited number of flags, it would be easy for a small group of users to delete an unlimited number of comments for no reason at all, and it would be difficult to detect them.

That said, it may be reasonable to ask to increase the number of comment flags you have per day.  See my comment on your question for the thread where that was discussed.

Comment: I thought they were visible? at `/tools/flagged`? (via "links")

Comment: @Marc: I only see offensive/spam flagged posts (questions and answers), not comments.  Unless, of course, I am being blind...

Comment: this is true, but comments also become more resistant to this sort of deletion as they get upvotes

Answer (score 0):

Flag for moderator attention, or email the team. They can clear out all the comments and warn/suspend the offending users.