# Show how many flags I have left

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, flags

Since the number of flags on a given day is limited (see the related questions below), I would like to see how many I have left before I flag a post.

This happens for me most often when I'm doing a retagging and need a diamond mod to retag a migrated question, but other people apparently run out of flags quickly on spammy posts.

I would like a simple "n flags remaining" just like the similar feature that was recently added to the vote-to-close screen.

---

Related questions:
[Should flagging limits be raised?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15487/should-flagging-limits-be-raised)
[Increase the number of daily spam flags with reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8935/increase-the-number-of-daily-spam-flags-with-reputation)

Comment: I think this is a great idea. When you're notified how many flags you have left, you are able to use them more wisely.

Comment: @Jon: For me at least, I don't want to run out in case I have to flag something that is actually important. :)

Comment: That just replaces "how many do I have left" with "what are the chances I might need this remaining vote for something more important".  What if you later find *two* posts you *really* want to flag?  If it's that important, wait less than 24h and flag it then---if it's still around.

Comment: I run out of flags on most days I am active, since I try to check the 10k tools at least once.

Comment: @Gnome: That's why I included the related questions, which suggest, essentially, increasing the number of flags allowed, or removing the limit completely. If the latter happens, then this feature request is moot, certainly.