# How to keep track of flags I raised

Tags: support, flags

I have flagged some questions on stackoverflow which, in my opinion, belong on superuser (mostly about bash). Now I keep finding similar questions, and I don't know which of them I have already flagged. I want to avoid annoying mods who might have already decided that that particular question really does belong on stackoverflow.

How do I keep track of the questions I have flaged for moderator attention?

Comment: Just gain 2,869 reps. :)

Comment: @Kenny: That doesn't really help either, as there's no way to track your close votes. ...or your reopen votes. ...or your delete votes. ...or your undelete votes. ;)

Comment: May also be interesting to read: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16720/can-the-flag-for-moderator-attention-have-a-feedback-mechanism

Comment: A related note, moderator flag messages are actually retained even after they have been cleared. There's currently no mechanism to retrieve them without re-flagging the post, but there's [another feature request for that as well](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/59932/make-flags-for-mod-attention-archivable).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Currently, there's no way to do this besides writing it down somewhere.

That being said, due to the system not [allowing more than one flag on a single post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/15487/should-flagging-limits-be-raised), you can't accidentally flag the same post twice.

Comment: you can however re-flag once the flag is cleared

Comment: Give the flag another shot

Comment: @Jeff: It does not appear to work. I got the usual "You have already flagged this post for moderator attention."